# SSIS row field to be sum of lookup

Tags: ssis, lookup

I have an SSIS data flow in SSIS 2012 project.

I need to calculate in the best way possible for every row field a sum of another table based on some criteria.

It would be something like a lookup but returning an aggregate on the lookup result.

Is there an SSIS way to do it by components or i need to turn to script task or stored procedure?

Example:

One data flow has a filed names LOT.

i need to get the sum(quantity) from table b where dataflow.LOT = tableb.lot

and write this back to a flow field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the Lookup Component. Instead of selecting `tableb` write the query, thus

```
SELECT
    B.Lot -- for matching
,   SUM(B.quantity) AS TotalQuantity -- for data flow injection
FROM
    tableb AS B
GROUP BY
    B.Lot;
```

Now when the package begins, it will first run this query against that data source and generate the quantities across all lots.

This may or may not be a good thing based on data volumes and whether the values in tableB are changing. In the larger volume case, *if* it's a problem, then I'd look at whether I can do something about the above query. Maybe I only need current year's data. Maybe my list of Lots could be pushed into the remove server beforehand to only compute the aggregates for what I need.

If TableB is very active, then you might need to change your caching from the default of Full to a Partial or None. If Lot 10 shows up twice in the data flow, the None would perform 2 lookups against the source while the Partial would cache the values it has seen. Probably, depends on memory pressure, etc.

Comment: So obvious!! thanks. Table B does NOT contain too many values . they will always be from 1.000-10.000 so i think that i will not face a problem to this area.